# Improve my script run time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

Is there anyway to improve my script run time? I have a script that creates 2 listboxes: `Listbox1` items is all my google site pages, `listbox2` items is the sub-pages of `listbox1` page. The script runs fine but sometimes it takes between 2 and 5 seconds to get all of the `listbox2` items.

You can try my script [here](https://sites.google.com/site/phichdaica/).

And here is my script:

```
function doGet() 
{
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  //GUI with 2 listbox
  //Listbox1: onclick > lbox1onclick(e), onchange > lbox1onchange(e)
  app.add(app.loadComponent("MyUrlParser")); 
  var lbox1 = app.getElementById('ListBox1');
  lbox1.addItem(' ');
  var lbox1_Item = SitesApp.getSite('phichdaica').getChildByName('manga').getChildren();
  for(var i = lbox1_Item.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
      lbox1.addItem(lbox1_Item[i].getTitle());
  }
  return app;  

}

function lbox1onclick(e)
{
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var lbox2 = app.getElementById('ListBox2');
  lbox2.clear();
  return app;
}

function lbox1onchange(e)
{
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  // var value = e.parameter.lbox1;
  var lbox1value = e.parameter.ListBox1;
  var lbox2 = app.getElementById('ListBox2');


  var lbox2_Item = SitesApp.getSite('phichdaica').getChildByName('manga').getChildByName(lbox1value).getChildren();

  for(var i=lbox2_Item.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    lbox2.addItem(lbox2_Item[i].getTitle());
  }
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it will speed up the process but you could use just one handler function to do that : on change  listBox1, clear listBox 2 and re-populate it immediately.  What is taking some time is the call to site's content so the difference might not be significative but the 'logic' of your script would be improved ;-)

Looking at your page, I see that listBox 2 is never cleared... is that a temporary issue ? Did you change something recently ?

Also, what is supposed to happen when something is selected in listBox2 ?

***EDIT*** : following your comment, if you want to improve user experience concerning the 'responsiveness' of your UI the best way is to use client handlers to trigger the visibility of a '*wait message*' for example(something like "*Updating the list*"). I usually use an animated gif that I made visible with a client handler and that is made invisible again when the server handler returns (ie I set it invisible in the server handler function).

here is a [working example](https://docs.google.com/macros/exec?service=AKfycbyc2SWv6JhDgUpXwF7aAARihIE7WPRmrQf6KIOtfQ), just try to change the date in the upper right corner.

Comment: Hi Serge,
Thanks for the advise. I used 2 handlers because when change in listbox1 it took 1-3sec (sometime 5sec), people will think listbox2 (not updated yet) items is all the subpage. And i think with the onclick handler will not increase the run time. Because when you click on listbox1 and you must spend time to pick an item. That why i removed lbox2.clear() in onchange function.